# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, nullpointerexception

i got this exception everytime i try to load my webapp:

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:538)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:22)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

how can i solve this exception?

Comment: I have the same error, I tried below solutions but still am getting the error, any help please.....

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced the same problem.
I got the solution to solve this problem.

Root of this problem is: 
I had added the servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar in my application lib directory. If Apache-tomcat is used to run application then its not necessary to add this jar files in our lib directory.

Solution:

- Goto build Path -> add external jars from tomcat-lib dir.
- Instead of adding(copying) it in lib dir of application.

If have any problem, contact me.

Comment: I do not have those jar files in my lib. I only have apache tomcat libraries on the build path. But still i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Set the keepgenerated configuration of Tomcat to true (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), clean tomcat's work directory, restart tomcat, reproduce the problem, and look what happens in index_jsp.java at line 22. It probably is some scriptlet which generates this exception. (and you should avoid scriptlets. See [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Replace the 7 by a 6 in the URL I gave you, and you'll find the same doc for Tomcat 6. Not too hard, is it? And you might find this website helpful: http://www.google.com

Comment: thanks, and no need for making jokes, we're all learning here...

Comment: Yes, but you're also supposed to show some research effort. Finding documentation on Tomcat isn't hard at all, especially if you already have the URL for the documentation of another version.